# ruby get value with input separate

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i am trying to get value from my get.chomp

```
total_user_input = []

while true
    print "Input Name: "
    user_input = gets.chomp
    break if user_input.empty?
    total_user_input << user_input
end

File.open("file.txt", "w") do |f|
f.write(
  total_user_input.each do |input|
    f.print input
  end
)
```

and the scirpt run like this:

```
Input Name: name:string
Input Name: price:integer
Input Name: description:date
```

and the result that i want is:

```
name: String
price: Integer
description: Date
```

Comment: what is the concrete issue?

Comment: the issue is in file.txt  i just got name:stirng price:integer description:date  but the result that i want is name: String price: Integer description: Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capitalize second word

```
input = "name:string"

input.split(":").reduce {|first, second| "#{first}: #{second.capitalize}"}

# => name: String
```